# emacs: turning electric-indent-mode on/off easily

Tags: emacs, initialization, elisp, indentation

I'm a bit of an elisp newbie. How can I tell emacs to toggle electric-indent-mode when I press "C-c e" ?

I tried

```
 (global-set-key (kbd "C-c e") 'toggle-electric-indent-mode)
```

but that does't seem to do it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mode is just a function that you can call. Try:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c e") 'electric-indent-mode)
```